# Choose photo albums to backup/upload to Onedrive

Tags: onedrive, photos, backup

On my phone I have three photo albums: Camera Roll, Saved Pictures and Screenshots. The first two get automatically uploaded to Onedrive with the "backup" feature. I'd also like the Screenshots album to upload, how can I achieve that?

User voice suggestion post: https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3412004-have-screenshots-album-honor-auto-upload-settings-

Answer (score 1):

Easiest method is open the photo (in `Screenshots`) with a photo editing app and save (to `Saved Pictures`).

Comment: That's how to do it manually. I want it to happen automatically.

Answer (score -2):

With Onedrive you cannot map , but you can install apps from box , dropbox and select the desired folder to sync .