# How to map whatsapp images to Onedrive?

Tags: lumia, onedrive, whatsapp

Before last Whatsapp update for my Windows Phone, images were getting stored under saved pictures and I was able to see them in Onedrive, but after latest update I am no longer able to send my WhatsApp images to Onedrive? How can I do this ?

Answer (score 5):

In latest update of WhatsApp, images are stored in WhatsApp folder in Pictures folder. You can find the same in Albums. These folder might not sync with the Onedrive. May be this [question](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2660/choose-photo-albums-to-backup-upload-to-skydrive/2672#2672) might help.

Answer (score 3):

After update 356 of whatsapp, the pictures get saved to Other Pictures folder in Photos. I was wondering why the pictures weren't automatically getting saved to the Whatsapp folder like my old files. On closer inspection, they were just being saved to a different folder. I do not know how to change this setting. But at least there is a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Your photos can be automatically backed up if you ticked the option in Go to Settings > swipe over to "Applications" Tap photos + camera > swipe down the screen and you should see the following.Otherwise, you can do it by pressing "share" and then "Onedrive".
[image]

And if you want to upload a picture (saved in other folder, maybe) you need to open the OneDrive app, select a folder and then upload it.

Hope it works for you ;)

Regards,
Joseph Paul